# Ionic 3 - Local notification popup/ heads up does not show

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic3, uilocalnotification

I have been trying to implement push using FCM and handling it with ionic 3 local notifications. The issue I am facing is that the notification is being received but only the notification icon appears and the notification lies in the android notification tray/area. I need the heads-up/ popup to be shown to the user when he/she receives a notification.

**I have already tried to set the foreground as true , setting priority to maximum ( 2 ), using a different version. I am still not able to find the solution.**

The plugin version and the code that I am using

```
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.3"

"phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.2.3"
```

For Push the code is as below :

```
const options: PushOptions = {
            android: {
                senderID: "728748838135",
                sound: "default",
                forceShow: true
            },
            ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: true,
                sound: "true"
            },
            windows: {},
            browser: {
                pushServiceURL: "http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push"
            }
        };
    pushObject.on("notification").subscribe((notification: any) => {
                console.log(
                    "Received a notification",
                    notification,
                    JSON.stringify(notification.message)
                );
```

For handling local notification :

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
                silent: false,
                id: 1,
                title: "Cashberry",
                text: notification.message,
                led: "FF0000",
                sound: "default",
                priority: 2,
                foreground: true
            });
```

**Expected Behaviour :** The notification heads up should appear in background as well as foreground for the user.

**Current Behaviour :** No notification heads up appears.Only icon is shown at top and notification resides in notifications tray.

Comment: Hi prateek, i am facing the same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: Actually for the foreground notifications I am handling it with a toast. For the background notifications we made changes in the payload that we were sending in the notification and it worked without the local notification.

Also, I am using     "@ionic-native/push": "^4.20.0",
with "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.2.3".

Comment: I have tried by changing payload. Mostly tried each possibility. Can you please share your payload?